# DialogFlow CX syntax for conditional blocks and responses

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

With google's new visual DialogFlow CX builder
I am passing in a parameter to a Flow.
The simulator shows the parameter is set and I can access it with `$session.params.anger`
but wondering how session/page/intent params are set.

Also what is the syntax for these conditional blocks. There seems to be some odd bash like syntax. It seems an `if/else/endif` works and has basic syntax highlighting, but I just found that out by trial and error. Is there any documentation on this? Maybe its a common feature from ES?

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter

[image: anger]

Answer (score 8):

There are different ways on how to define and set [Parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter) for [Dialogflow CX](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs). You can check the following examples for more information.

1. Intent Parameters

   a. Defined during design-time
   [image: intent parameters]
   b. Set during runtime

   i. Any parameters used by annotating a training phrase as seen from the screenshot above will be captured from the user query and will be set by Dialogflow as an Intent parameter (**$intent.params.parameter-name**).

   ii. By using [Parameter Presets](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment#param-preset)
   [image: parameter presets]
2. Form Parameters or Page Parameters

   a. Define during design-time
   [image: form parameters]
   b. Set during runtime

   i. Any form/page parameters as seen from the screenshot above will be captured from the user query and will be set by Dialogflow as a Page parameter (**$page.params.parameter-name**).

   ii. By using [Parameter Presets](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment#param-preset) (*refer to 1.b.ii for example*)

   iii. By setting the **pageInfo.formInfo.parameterInfo** field in the [Webhook response](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3beta1#webhookresponse)

```
{
    "pageInfo": {
        "formInfo": {
            "parameterInfo": {
                "displayName": "geo-city",
                "value": "New York",
                "state": "FILLED"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Session Parameters

   a. Set during runtime

   i. Captured Intent and Page parameters are also written to Dialogflow’s session as Session parameters (**$session.params.parameter-name**).

   ii. By using [Parameter Presets](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment#param-preset) (*refer to 1.b.ii for example*)

   iii. By setting the **sessionInfo.parameters** field in the Webhook response

```
{
    "sessionInfo": {
        "parameters": {
            "city": "New York"
        }
    }
}
```

iv. By setting the **queryParams.parameters** request field for the Session type in a detectIntent request while using the API (example below is using [detectIntent for REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3beta1/projects.locations.agents.sessions/detectIntent))

```
curl \
-X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
--data "{
  'queryInput': {
    'text': {
      'text': 'howdy'
    },
    'languageCode': 'en'
  },
  'queryParams': {
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
    'parameters': {
      'displayName': 'geo-city',
      'value': 'New York'
    }
  }
}" \
"https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v3beta1/projects/<project-id>/locations/global/agents/<agent-id>/sessions/1234567890:detectIntent"
```

For [conditional responses](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/condition), I have also tried to experiment with this type of response and the following syntax worked for me:

```
if <condition>
  <block> //response to be returned
elif <condition>
  <block>
elif <condition>
  <block>
else
  <block>
endif
```

[image: result]

Comment: this is an extremely detailed reply, thank you! do you work for google!? I'm working on a github wiki with "intermediate level" CX topics. would you care to check it out? twitter DM me @dcsan

Comment: I found for responses you don't need `params.name.resolved` just `params.name` seems to work...

Comment: [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment#cond) has been updated.

Comment: Correction: `pageInfo.formInfo.parameterInfo` accepts an array, not an object (see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3beta1#google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3beta1.PageInfo.FormInfo)). Otherwise great anwser, thanks!